# Valuations in Higher-dimensional local fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, algebraic-number-theory, local-fields

I have the following question which I believ should be true but I would like to have a different opinion about it:

Let $M/L$ is a finite Galois extension of $n$-dimensional local fields and $t_1,\dots, t_n$ is a system of local parameters for $M$ with corresponding valuation $v=(v_1,\dots, v_d)$. If $g$ is an element in $Gal(M/L)$ then is it true that $v\circ g=v$?

Any insight about it would be appreciated.

Thanks